# Vue Quasar - Qselect with async data defaulting to [object Object]

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, quasar-framework

In my created() area I have a call to Firestore that fills a array I’ve setup in my data area named ebscoCachedSearchesController. It is an array of objects and I have the objects set properly to show in the qselect. When the select shows it displays as if an option has already been selected and that is [object Object]. However! When I click on the select I see all the options I expect to see and can click them and everything from that point works as desired.

How to I get rid of [object Object] and have the qselect be in its base state until I click on it?

In the template:

```html
 <q-card-section>
        <template v-if="ebscoCachedSearchesController.length > 0">
          <q-select
            dark
            :options="ebscoCachedSearchesController"
            v-model="ebscoTemp"
            filled
            label="Cached Search to Use"
          >
          </q-select
        >
        </template>
      </q-card-section>
```

In created():

```js
this.$firestore.collection("ebsco-searches").onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
    this.ebscoCachedSearchesController = [];
    querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
      let rObj = {};
      rObj.name = doc.data().searchTerm;
      rObj.label = doc.data().searchTerm;
      rObj.value = doc.data().searchTerm;
      rObj.id = doc.id;
      rObj.selected = false;
      this.ebscoCachedSearchesController.push(rObj);
      this.ebsco_a9h_loading = false;
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the thing I'm v-modeling is an empty object to start. If I instantiate that with a label and value it shows that to start.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to instantiate your model (`ebscoTemp`) with `null`.